# Show the history of a State Machine/Workflow

Tags: workflow, jbpm, state-machine-workflow

I'm trying to find a way to represent graphically the history of an operation inside an state machine. So if the operation has gone through `state_1>state_2>state_3>state_2>state_4>end` I would like to see that path visually.

We are using a Web-UI and a Java Backend, so any HTML-JS or Java library (that creates image files or something like this) should be ok for us. We are using JBMN for parts of the state machine, my initial approach was to find something related with it, but I haven't found anything

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do some crazy animations? or just highlight the states that were already executed?
If you want to do that, you can use the jbpm designer that already provide that functionality.

Cheers